# What do squared brackets do in this context in Python?

Tags: python, brackets

I'm trying to understand a script in Python for an assignment but I don't know what square brackets mean when used in a variable's name. This is the code:

```
import numpy as np

if __name__ == "__main__":
        
    epsilonff = 94.45
    sigmaff = 3.575
    delta = 0.01*sigmaff
    L = 10*sigmaff

    rhob = 0.004959169999999999/sigmaff**3
    kT = 77.4
    beta = 1.0/kT

    sigmasf, epssf, rhov, Delta = 3.494, 53.22, 0.114, 3.35

    x = np.arange(0,L,delta)+0.5*delta
    N = x.size

    def Vsteele(z,sigmaw,epsw,rhov,Delta):
        return 2*np.pi*rhov*epsw*sigmaw**2*Delta*((sigmaw/z)**10-(sigmaw/z)**4-sigmaw**4/(3*Delta*(z+0.61*Delta)**3))

    Vext = beta*Vsteele(x,sigmasf,epssf,rhov,Delta)+beta*Vsteele(L-x,sigmasf,epssf,rhov,Delta)

    print(f'rhob is = {rhob}')
```

```
rhob is = 1.08537761e-04
```

I can understand that, but the following I don't get.

```
    n = rhob*np.ones(N,dtype=np.float32)
    nsig = int(0.5*sigmaff/delta)
    mask = Vext>beta*1e4
    n[mask] = 1.0e-16
    Vext[mask] = beta*1e4
```

Shouldn't the first line make an array of 1s with length N? yet this is my output: (I'd say is because of the squared brackets but I don't how do they affect)

```
[1.00000000e-16 1.00000000e-16 1.00000000e-16 1.00000000e-16
 1.00000000e-16 1.00000000e-16 1.00000000e-16 1.00000000e-16
 1.00000000e-16 1.00000000e-16 1.00000000e-16 1.00000000e-16
 1.00000000e-16 1.00000000e-16 1.00000000e-16 1.00000000e-16
 1.00000000e-16 1.00000000e-16 1.00000000e-16 1.00000000e-16
 1.00000000e-16 1.00000000e-16 1.00000000e-16 1.00000000e-16
 1.00000000e-16 1.00000000e-16 1.00000000e-16 1.00000000e-16
 1.00000000e-16 1.00000000e-16 1.00000000e-16 1.00000000e-16
 1.00000000e-16 1.00000000e-16 1.00000000e-16 1.00000000e-16
 1.00000000e-16 1.00000000e-16 1.00000000e-16 1.00000000e-16
 1.00000000e-16 1.00000000e-16 1.00000000e-16 1.00000000e-16
 1.00000000e-16 1.00000000e-16 1.00000000e-16 1.00000000e-16
 1.00000000e-16 1.00000000e-16 1.00000000e-16 1.00000000e-16
 1.00000000e-16 1.00000000e-16 1.00000000e-16 1.00000000e-16
 1.00000000e-16 1.00000000e-16 1.00000000e-16 1.00000000e-16
 1.00000000e-16 1.00000000e-16 1.00000000e-16 1.00000000e-16
 1.00000000e-16 1.00000000e-16 1.00000000e-16 1.00000000e-16
 1.00000000e-16 1.00000000e-16 1.00000000e-16 1.00000000e-16
 1.00000000e-16 1.00000000e-16 1.00000000e-16 1.00000000e-16
 1.00000000e-16 1.00000000e-16 1.00000000e-16 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04 1.08537761e-04
 1.08537761e-04 1.00000000e-16 1.00000000e-16 1.00000000e-16
 1.00000000e-16 1.00000000e-16 1.00000000e-16 1.00000000e-16
 1.00000000e-16 1.00000000e-16 1.00000000e-16 1.00000000e-16
 1.00000000e-16 1.00000000e-16 1.00000000e-16 1.00000000e-16
 1.00000000e-16 1.00000000e-16 1.00000000e-16 1.00000000e-16
 1.00000000e-16 1.00000000e-16 1.00000000e-16 1.00000000e-16
 1.00000000e-16 1.00000000e-16 1.00000000e-16 1.00000000e-16
 1.00000000e-16 1.00000000e-16 1.00000000e-16 1.00000000e-16
 1.00000000e-16 1.00000000e-16 1.00000000e-16 1.00000000e-16
 1.00000000e-16 1.00000000e-16 1.00000000e-16 1.00000000e-16
 1.00000000e-16 1.00000000e-16 1.00000000e-16 1.00000000e-16
 1.00000000e-16 1.00000000e-16 1.00000000e-16 1.00000000e-16
 1.00000000e-16 1.00000000e-16 1.00000000e-16 1.00000000e-16
 1.00000000e-16 1.00000000e-16 1.00000000e-16 1.00000000e-16
 1.00000000e-16 1.00000000e-16 1.00000000e-16 1.00000000e-16
 1.00000000e-16 1.00000000e-16 1.00000000e-16 1.00000000e-16
 1.00000000e-16 1.00000000e-16 1.00000000e-16 1.00000000e-16
 1.00000000e-16 1.00000000e-16 1.00000000e-16 1.00000000e-16
 1.00000000e-16 1.00000000e-16 1.00000000e-16 1.00000000e-16
 1.00000000e-16 1.00000000e-16 1.00000000e-16 1.00000000e-16]
```

Comment: You could produce this with a couple of lines of code. Why post all the other stuff? See how to create a [mcve].

Comment: "Shouldn't the first line make an array of 1s with length N?" - if you wanted ones, why did you multiply by `rhob`?

Comment: Which square brackets do you not understand exactly? There are several of them in the example you have shown. Do you mean `n[mask]`? Or `[1.00000000e-16 1.00000000e-16 ...`?

Comment: `n = rhob*np.ones(N,dtype=np.float32)`  creates an array with values rhob then mask equates to True so that n[mask] = 1.0e-16 changes the array n to be filled with values 1.0e0-16.

Comment: @user2357112 sorry meant array of rhob with lenght N

Comment: @mkrieger1 Earlier they talked about "when used in a variable's name", so seems to be `n[mask] = ...` and `Vext[mask] = ...` (i.e. `__setitem__()`)

Comment: @mkrieger1 I meant that I don't get why my output isn't an array of "rhob" with lenght N

Comment: Okay. Well because you change the array between creating it as an array of "rhob" with length N and printing it.

Comment: Opposite question: [Change values of a numpy array based on certain condition](/q/46022688/4518341)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Square brackets are used in Python to index into or slice list-like objects. NumPy extends the base index functionality and allows boolean expressions to select subsets of its array objects. In your case, you are modifying every value in the array that satisfies the `mask` condition.

See the Python documentation:
[An Informal Introduction to Python - Lists](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists)

and the NumPy docs: [Indexing on ndarrays](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html)